# adding new objects to array within a loop with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a `for` loop that needs to make an `AJAX` call with a one second delay between iterations. It should grab the object and `.push` it onto the array. The code below only adds the first object. What am I doing wrong?

```
var maxLoops = 10;
var counter = 0;

(function processPages() {
    if(counter++ >= maxLoops) return;

    setTimeout(function() {
        //check page count and loop. push all new objects into allProducts
        for (var i=1; i <= totalPages; i++){
            $.ajax({ url: '/process.php',
                data: {category: 'sportingGoods', page: i},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) {
                    allProducts.push(output);
                }
            })
        }
        }), 1000;
})();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match the description at all.

Comment: You wait, then do a few ajax calls, all at the same time, then it's the end. Is your goal to wait between those ajax calls ?

Comment: besides, where does `totalPages` come from? And why do you `push(response)` instead of `push(output)`?

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing and/or over complicating this. I want to make 10 AJAX calls and push the returned objects to an array. I need the delay due to API restrictions

Comment: Your for-loop should be outside the timeout function, the ajax call should be the only thing within. Now you're looping 1 till "totalPages" all in once.

Comment: @Joshua-Pendo sorry, that was a copy/paste error. This is a snippet from a larget AJAX call

Comment: I also guess `totalPages` must be `counter` in the for-loop?

Comment: OK, I think I get the goal. I've answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a few ajax calls and wait between them, you can do this:

```
(function processPages(i) {
    if (i===totalPages) {
         // all the pages have been fetched, you may
         // use the allProducts array here
         return;
    }
    $.ajax({ url: '/process.php',
        data: {category: 'sportingGoods', page: i},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            allProducts.push(output);
            setTimeout(processPages, 1000, i+1);
        }
    })
})(0);
```

This will stop when `i` is `totalPages`.

Comment: So don't forget `totalPages` is actually the `maxLoops` var you've created in  your example

Comment: hmmm... still returning 1 result

Comment: You need to wait 10 seconds before trying to display the results.

Comment: @PaulDessert Check `totalPages`? Do the AJAX calls all succeed? Because there's no failure callback, this will halt operation on a failure of any of the calls.

Comment: @RGraham looks like a made a slight mistake on `totalPages`. It was actullay set to 100, not 10. Lots of network activity ;)

Comment: @PaulDessert A console.log right before $.ajax might help figure what happens

Comment: @DenysSéguret - Thanks, it's almost working as expected. The only issue is that the first result is the only object. The rest are not

Comment: *"The only issue is that the first result is the only object."* I don't understand your comment. Are you sure you wait for all pages ? I'll edit

Comment: Why call the IIFE with `()` instead of `(0)`? You're the only one that could call this function so you can control exactly which arguments are passed to it. It gets rid of the need for the `i = i || 0;` guard too. Lastly, why leave `totalPages` a free variable?

Comment: Also, the `setTimeout(processPages, 1000, i+1)` is only [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Browser_compatibility) in `IE >= 10`. I would recommend `setTimeout(function() { processPages(i+1); }, 1000);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxLoops = 10;
var counter = 0;

(function processPages() {
    if (counter++ >= maxLoops) return;
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //check page count and loop. push all new objects into allProducts
            $.ajax({
                url: '/process.php',
                data: {category: 'sportingGoods', page: i},
                type: 'post',
                success: function (output) {
                    allProducts.push(output);
                    if(allProducts.length === totalPages){
                        // call final function  - array filled
                    }
                }
            })
        }, 1000 * i);
    }
})();
```

Like this?

Comment: Why would you increase the delay with `1000 * (i+1)`, this would make the script wait 10 seconds before executing after the 9th iteration?

Comment: @Joshua-Pendo take a moment to comprehend the code. The `for-loop` is synchronous and will not *wait* for the `$.ajax` call to finish before the loop continues. This is a hack way of creating all the timeouts at once, but spacing them out like an interval. I don't recommend it, but it can work.

Comment: @Joshua-Pendo paste this in a repl to see what it does: `for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { setTimeout(function() { console.log("hi"); }, 1000*i); }`

Comment: It's habitual for me use loop from 0 )